# PHP - ECDSA - Public key (json) to Pem Format

Tags: php, public-key, pem

I'm stuck from yesterday, I can't find any way to do what I need...
I have a public key (json) that we get from an API and I need to convert it in Pem format because I need to verify the signature (with lcobucci library)
I'm using PHP 5.5.9 (for my work)

I have something like this :

```
"kty": "EC",
"kid": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
"use": "sig"
"crv": "P-384",
"x": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"y": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

And I would like to have this :

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEZe2loSV3wrroKUN/4zhwGhCqo3Xh
u1td4QjeQ5wIVR0eUu11cBFj9/nkDd+fNBs9ybqGCvfgynyn6e7NAITRnA==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

If you have any idea how to do it with php (library) it could be great.
Thanks to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

**300a**: This is the beginning of the SubjectPublicKeyInfo sequence, indicating the start of a constructed sequence.

**3003**: The length of the SubjectPublicKeyInfo sequence, indicating that the next three bytes specify the content.

**a003**: This is the beginning of the AlgorithmIdentifier sequence, specifying the algorithm used to generate the public key. In ECC, it includes the OID (Object Identifier) for the elliptic curve.

**020101**: This is an INTEGER with the value 01, indicating that the following value is the OID.

**300506032b6570**: This is the OID for the elliptic curve. In this case, it's 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7, which corresponds to the prime256v1 (secp256r1) elliptic curve.

**034200**: This is the actual uncompressed ECC public key. The 03 indicates that the following value is a BIT STRING, and 4200 is the length of the BIT STRING. The leading 42 indicates that the public key is composed of 66 (hex) octets, corresponding to the uncompressed public key (the 04 prefix followed by the x and y coordinates).

```
    $curveOID = '06082a8648ce3d030107';//'1.2.840.10045.3.1.7'; //prime256v1 CURVE NAME - CHANGE TO YOUR CURVE HEX
    $userPublicKey = base64url_decode($subscription->keys->p256dh);
    $subjectPublicKeyInfo = hex2bin('3059301306072a8648ce3d0201'.$curveOID.'034200'.bin2hex($userPublicKey));

    $pem = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----".PHP_EOL;
    $pem .= chunk_split(base64_encode($subjectPublicKeyInfo), 64, PHP_EOL);
    $pem .= "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

    echo $pem.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;


    $userPublicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($pem);
    if(!$userPublicKey){
        throw new Exception('Unable to compute user public key');
    }
```